# Draw2D / GEF: How to access nested figures (e.g., for connections)

Tags: java, eclipse, casting, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I'm currently learning GEF (as in the Eclipse project), and while doing so have come across a question.

In my future application I will have to connect a `Figure` with the nested figure of some other `Figure`. I have found that via the following code (quoted from memory, used in a pure Draw2D application) I can access the nested figure.

```
(Figure)someFigure.getChildren().get(1)
```

From trying it out I have found out that when the accessed `Figure` has added to it a) a `Label` and b) a `Figure` (`add()`ed in this order), the above code will return the nested `Figure`.

Obviously this isn't optimal, as the same code with `get(0)` will probably result in an error (I guess a casting error).

My question is: Is there a native/easier way to access nested figures, especially without having to cast?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think there is a way. If you own the code that adds the figures, why not create your own model instead of relying on `draw2d` (BTW, this is what [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/gef_mvc/index.php) does).

Comment: Thanks! Now that I've walked a bit further along the path so to speak, I understand what you mean :). Yes, I do own the code, and thus will be able to access the figures much better... Btw, thanks for the amazing `GEF` Editor tut you have on your blog! Reeeeeally good! For everyone looking after an answer to a `GEF` question, here it is: http://www.vainolo.com/2011/06/12/creating-a-gef-editor-part-1-defining-the-model-2/.